# Solution of a special case of Abel's differential equation of the second kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My teacher mentioned to the class the following case of Abel's equation:

$$y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-y=Ax+B$$ where $A, B\in \Bbb R $. I have thoroughly searched the Web, but I haven't found a certain sufficient way to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{A\,x+B+y}{y}.
$$
The change of variable $A\,x+B=t$ transforms it into
$$
A\,\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t+y}{y},
$$
a homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 3):

Two changes of variables transform the non-linear ODE to an ODE on separable kind. The solution is expressed on implicite form :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a general solution from the Polyanin textbook for the equation,

$y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-y=Ax+B$

The solution in parametric form is

$x = C \cdot e^{-\int \frac {t \cdot dt}{t^2-t-A}} $

and

$y = C \cdot t \cdot e^{-\int \frac {t \cdot dt}{t^2-t-A}} $

Although, it does not show how it was derived.